# Questions about Excel worksheet embedding in WinForms application

Tags: .net, excel

I embed Excel worksheet in a WinForms C# application in two ways - using WebBrowser control and using dsoFramer control. In both cases i'm facing the following two problems:
1. How do i make my embedded spreadsheet read-only? The only way i discovered is by protecting the underlying Excel file, but it causes annoying message boxes to pop up all the time.
2. If i launch MS Excel in a separate process prior to launching my application, the standalone Excel freezes after my embedded worksheet is shown.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered the case that your user's may not have Excel on their PC, or is that a non issue?

Comment: schooner: this feature of my application is activated only if Excel is present; otherwise, i'm using a different UI component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) comes with an Excel compatible Windows Forms spreadsheet control which you can simply drag to your form. It includes a Workbook Designer which allows you to edit workbooks right in Visual Studio or load Excel workbooks from disk, and also includes a comprehensive API which is similar to Excel (except that it is .NET friendly).

You can [learn more](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/windowsforms.aspx) and try the [free evaluation](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) for yourself if this might work for you.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC